# spring MVC : form : radiobutton for boolean property not rendering in jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I have the code in jsp; The following code is inside a c:forEach loop.

```
 <td>
        <form:radiobutton  path="status" value="true"  class="radio onRadio" />
           <label class="lblOn">On</label>
        <form:radiobutton  path="status" value="false"  class="radio offRadio" />
           <label class="lblOff">Off</label>
    </td>
```

And in my pojo the property is:

```
public Class Channel{
    private boolean status= false;
 ......
}
```

and getters and setters

The serviceImpl is like:

```
 Channel oChannel = new Channel();

    /* active/inactive will comes from DB */

    if("active".equalsIgnoreCase("active")){
        oChannel.setStatus(true);
    }else{
        oChannel.setStatus(false);
    }
```

But in jsp i am getting Off selected for all the rows, where i am doing wrong? any help?

Answer (score 0):

try this change in service as  get("status") will be the value of you radio button and your checking with "active". Where 'active' comes from?

`if("active".equalsIgnoreCase(map.get("status").toString()))` to

`if("true".equalsIgnoreCase(map.get("status").toString()))`

Comment: map.get("status").toString() is actually part of my DB api, which will retrun "active" or "inactive" as stored in DB.

Comment: when i execute a query it returns a map to me, like key="column name" and value="col value"

Answer (score 0):

get One nasty solution for this time being:

```
<td>
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${status == 'true'}">
      <input type="radio" id="chStatusId" name="status" value="true" checked="checked"/>
      <label class="lblActive">Active</label>
      <input type="radio" id="chStatusId" name="status" value="false"/>
      <label class="lblInactive">Inactive</label>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${status == 'false'}">
      <input type="radio" id="chStatusId" name="status" value="true" />
      <label class="lblActive">Active</label>
      <input type="radio" id="chStatusId" name="status" value="false" checked="checked"/>
      <label class="lblInactive">Inactive</label>
   </c:when>
</c:choose> 
</td>
```